# Mongodb find query

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-java

seasons.json

```js
{
  "_id" : "unique_1",
  "spring" : [{
      "fruit" : "mango",
      "person_id" : [101.0, 102.0, 103.0, 104.0]
    }, {
      "fruit" : "banana",
      "person_id" : [151.0, 152.0, 153.0, 154.0]
    }],
  "summer" : [{
      "fruit" : "mango",
      "person_id" : [201.0, 202.0, 203.0, 204.0]
    }, {
      "fruit" : "banana",
      "person_id" : [251.0, 252.0, 253.0, 254.0]
    }],
  "fall" : [{
      "fruit" : "mango",
      "person_id" : [301.0, 302.0, 303.0, 304.0]
    }, {
      "fruit" : "banana",
      "person_id" : [351.0, 352.0, 353.0, 354.0]
    }],
  "winter" : [{
      "fruit" : "mango",
      "person_id" : [401.0, 402.0, 403.0]
    }, {
      "fruit" : "banana",
      "person_id" : [451.0, 452.0, 453.0]
    }]
}

/* 2 */
{
  "_id" : "unique_2",
  "spring" : [{
      "fruit" : "banana",
      "person_id" : [151.0, 152.0, 153.0, 154.0]
    }],
  "summer" : [{
      "fruit" : "mango",
      "person_id" : [201.0, 202.0, 203.0, 204.0]
    }, {
      "fruit" : "banana",
      "person_id" : [251.0, 252.0, 253.0, 254.0]
    }],
  "fall" : [{
      "fruit" : "banana",
      "person_id" : [351.0, 352.0, 353.0, 354.0]
    }],
  "winter" : [{
      "fruit" : "mango",
      "person_id" : [401.0, 402.0, 403.0]
    }, {
      "fruit" : "banana",
      "person_id" : [451.0, 452.0, 453.0]
    }]
}
```

Above JSON records shows which season which person has eaten mango and which has eaten banana.

Here's what I want to find:
when i know the _id(primary key) of the record in advance or prior to record finding -

1) all the person_id ranging from 101 - 350 in which person_id is unique
2) person_id eating only mango
3) total number of person in a record eating fruit either mango or banana.

Comment: Please show your effort (i.e. code) first.

Comment: I  find out person_id range within a season with a particular fruit- db.season.find({ "spring.person_id" : { "$elemMatch" : { "$gt" : 101, "$lt" : 104 } } });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a schema like this it's going to be pretty difficult to run queries of such a nature like the ones you require. Consider changing the schema such that you have for each subdocument, one main key say for instance `seasons` which can have four different array elements i.e. spring, summer, winter and fall. Change the schema to this:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "unique_1",
    "seasons" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "spring",
            "fruits" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "mango",
                    "person_id" : [ 
                        101, 
                        102, 
                        103, 
                        104
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "banana",
                    "person_id" : [ 
                        151, 
                        152, 
                        153, 
                        154
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "summer",
            "fruits" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "mango",
                    "person_id" : [ 
                        201, 
                        202, 
                        203, 
                        204
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "banana",
                    "person_id" : [ 
                        251, 
                        252, 
                        253, 
                        254
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "fall",
            "fruits" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "mango",
                    "person_id" : [ 
                        301, 
                        302, 
                        303, 
                        304
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "banana",
                    "person_id" : [ 
                        351, 
                        352, 
                        353, 
                        354
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "winter",
            "fruits" : [ 
                {
                    "name" : "mango",
                    "person_id" : [ 
                        401, 
                        402, 
                        403
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "name" : "banana",
                    "person_id" : [ 
                        451, 
                        452, 
                        453
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

With this schema it becomes much easier to run the following aggregation queries:

1) all the person_id ranging from 101 - 350 in which person_id is unique

```
var pipeline1 = [
    { "$match": { "_id": "unique_1" },
    { "$unwind": "$seasons" },
    { "$unwind": "$seasons.fruits" },
    { "$unwind": "$seasons.fruits.person_id" },
    {
        "$match": {
            "seasons.fruits.person_id": {
                "$gte": 101,
                "$lte": 350
            }
        }
    },    
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "person_ids": {
                "$addToSet": "$seasons.fruits.person_id"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "person_ids": 1
        }
    }
];

db.season.aggregate(pipeline1);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "person_ids" : [ 
                304, 
                253, 
                201, 
                251, 
                301, 
                203, 
                252, 
                204, 
                152, 
                102, 
                202, 
                154, 
                254, 
                101, 
                302, 
                153, 
                104, 
                103, 
                303, 
                151
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

2) person_id eating only mango

```
var pipeline2 = [
    { "$match": { "_id": "unique_1" },
    { "$unwind": "$seasons" },
    { "$unwind": "$seasons.fruits" },
    { "$unwind": "$seasons.fruits.person_id" },
    {
        "$match": {
            "seasons.fruits.name": "mango"
        }
    },    
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": 0,
            "person_ids": {
                "$addToSet": "$seasons.fruits.person_id"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "person_ids": 1
        }
    }
];

db.season.aggregate(pipeline2);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "person_ids" : [ 
                402.0000000000000000, 
                304.0000000000000000, 
                303.0000000000000000, 
                302.0000000000000000, 
                301.0000000000000000, 
                204.0000000000000000, 
                202.0000000000000000, 
                201.0000000000000000, 
                203.0000000000000000, 
                104.0000000000000000, 
                102.0000000000000000, 
                103.0000000000000000, 
                403.0000000000000000, 
                401.0000000000000000, 
                101.0000000000000000
            ]
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

3) total number of person in a record eating fruit either mango or banana.

```
var pipeline3 = [
    { "$match": { "_id": "unique_1" },
    { "$unwind": "$seasons" },
    { "$unwind": "$seasons.fruits" },
    { "$unwind": "$seasons.fruits.person_id" },
    {
        "$match": {
            "seasons.fruits.name": {
                "$in": ["mango", "banana"]
            }
        }
    },    
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "count": {
                "$sum": 1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "count": 1
        }
    }
];

db.season.aggregate(pipeline3);
```

**Output**:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "result" : [ 
        {
            "count" : 30
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: chrisdam -thanks a lot  for your detailed answer. But something get missed while pasting aggregate query method in your post. Its not running properly. I would be highly grateful to you, if you explain any one of the above query with detailed explaination .

Comment: @joshi No worries mate. Before you ran the aggregation queries, did you manage to change the schema? Sorry I couldn't well explain what each aggregation pipeline entailed since there were quite a handful of queries you needed and I assumed you knew the aggregation framework concepts hence why I delved straight into the implementation.

Comment: @chrisdam - yes, i did that change in db schema. but not able to run the aggregation query . Some brackets is misplaced from its location i think so.  As i m new to this bussiness & trying to adopt myself for mongodb framework. So for me, its not easy to walk through your code specially over the aggregation query, but i highly appreciate you for your speedy responses

Comment: Thanks @joshi. Please read the [**aggregation framework documentaion**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/) to grasp the basic concepts, that may help you understand the aggregation above better because it uses the same principles: when dealing with arrays, your aggregation is bound to have some `$unwind` operations that will allow you to easily do aggregation operations further down the pipeline.

Comment: @chrisdam -  i found a tutorial at http://www.thefourtheye.in/2013/04/mongodb-aggregation-framework-basics.html which i found very good for beginners  . Once again thanks chris for ur valuable inputs..

Comment: That's a very good tutorial @joshi, great find! All the best with your endeavours :-)