# mongodb schema optimization

Tags: json, django, mongodb, mongodb-query

Extension of earlier query at
[Mongodb find query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699516/mongodb-find-query][1])

Under a season different vendors sells different fruits and they arrange them inaccorance with shelf number. Below are some records which i have inserted in my mongodb - 
*vendor.json*

```
{
  "_id" : "vendor1",
  "shelf_1": ["Pear","Banana"],
  "shelf_2" : ["Grapes", "MuskMelon", "Apricot"],
  "shelf_3" : ["Pineapple, "Kiwi fruit"],
  "shelf_4" : ["Orange"],
  "shelf_5" : ["Guava","Lemon"]
}

{
  "_id" : "vendor2",
  "shelf_1": ["Mango","Banana"],
  "shelf_2" : ["Grapes", "MuskMelon", "Peach"],
  "shelf_3" : ["Pear, "Pulm"],
  "shelf_4" : ["Jackfruit"],
  "shelf_5" : ["Apple","Apricot"],
  "shelf_6": ["Avocado","Cherry"],
  "shelf_7" : ["Clementine", "Date", "Fig"],
  "shelf_8" : ["Guava, "Honeydew melon"],
  "shelf_9" : ["Lemon"],
  "shelf_10" : ["Kiwi fruit","Elderberry"],
  "shelf_11": ["Mysore Raspberry","Mountain Apple"],
  "shelf_12" : ["Starfruit", "Scrub Cherry", "Pomegranate"],
  "shelf_13" : ["Sugar Apple, "Tropical Appricot"],
  "shelf_14" : ["chinese chestnut",passion fruit],
  "shelf_15" : ["Raspberry","Wax Apple"],
  "shelf_16": ["Blueberries"],
  "shelf_17" : ["Strawberry", "Ugli fruit", "Watermelon"],
  "shelf_18" : ["Quince, "Satsuma","quince"],
  "shelf_19" : ["Pineapple"],
  "shelf_20" : ["Peanut","Orange","blackcurrant","lime","nectarine"]
}
{
  "_id" : "vendor3",
  "shelf_1": ["Mango","Banana"],
  "shelf_2" : ["Jackfruit"],
  "shelf_3" : ["Lemon, "Pulm","Pineapple"],
  "shelf_4" : ["Orange","Guava"],
  "shelf_5" : ["Apple","Apricot"],
  "shelf_6": ["Avocado","Cherry"],
  "shelf_7" : ["Pomegranate", "Date", "Fig"],
  "shelf_8" : ["Watermelon"],
  "shelf_9" : ["Kiwi fruit","Strawberry"]
}
```

I have added index on both shelf and on each fruit. Here each shelf's contains unique fruit and the arrangement of fruits in those shelf's
are different for different vendors.

I want to use above schema to

1. find a fruit from shelf available with vendor, when vendor is known to
2. find total number of shelf used by a particular vendor. 
   So any suggestion regarding the schema which i have created to run above two queries

Comment: The one possible way of optimizaion is -
{ _id : "vendor1",
Shelf: [{
          "number" : "shelf_1",
          "fruits" : ["Pear","Banana"]
        }, {
          "number" : "Shelf_2",
          "fruits" : ["Grapes", "MuskMelon", "Apricot"]
        },{
          "number" : "shelf_3",
          "fruits" : ["Pineapple, "Kiwi fruit"]
        }, {
          "number" : "Shelf_4",
          "fruits" : ["Orange"]
        },{
          "number" : "shelf_5",
          "fruits" : ["Guava","Lemon"]
        }]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While over normalizing imposes serious problems, you have under normalized your schema.

1. It does not scale well. As of the time of this writing, there is a [16MB size limit on BSON documents](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size). If you have a very large vendor, you (theoretically) might run into problems. Imagine WalMart with thousands of shelves in different locations. Remember Facebook has to pays huge amounts of money because they vastly underestimated the need to scale.
2. With your current schema, you have to have an arbitrary number of indices when you want to index all shelves. Setting aside other problems: building an index isn't free, even when done in background.
3. Only one index will be utilized per query. So we need to reduce the number of indices.
4. The questions you are asking don't even need this schema. Both of the time, the vendor is known. So you can easily use a more conventional approach, with easy and efficient queries.

Here is how I would do it. I'd have a vendor schema with stuff like name and location. Next, I'd have a shelf schema. Each shelf will have a reference to a vendor, like in SQL. The only thing is that those references are "weak", so to say. But since the vendor is known, so is his `_id` to query the shelf schema.

## The vendor schema

This is pretty straightforward

```
{
  '_id': new ObjectId(),
  'name': 'Acme Mart',
  'location': {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [ 34.180278, -118.328333 ]
  }
}
```

## The shelf schema

Actually it is quite easy, too

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId(),
  vendor: "idOfVendor",
  description: "Shelf 14"
  contents: ["Apples", "Oranges", "Kiwi" ]
}
```

## The indices

Setting aside the geospatial index we would need for the vendors `location` field, here are the indices you need

```
// Only if you want to search by name
db.vendors.ensureIndex({name:1})

// we use a compound index here
db.shelves.ensureIndex({vendor:1,contents:1})
```

You could even use a text index on `contents`, enabling the search to find both "apples" and "apple" to be found via "apples", but that's on you to decide.

## Your queries

Since the vendor is known, and thus his `_id`, we can easily find all shelves containing Kiwi:

```
db.shelves.find({vendor:"idOfVendor", contents: "Kiwi"})
```

Counting the number of shelves becomes even simpler:

```
db.shelves.find({vendor:"idOfVendor"}).count()
```

Comment: Thanks Markus for your valuable suggestion. But is it a good approach to create shelf and vendor two different collection . How creating a vendor collection making  a difference  since its information can easily get embedded in shelves collections.

Comment: @joshi: why would you want to do that? You'd have to change the vendor in each shelf if he moves. There is no drawback with the schema presented, but it eliminates all weaknesses in terms of scalability, superfluous and hard to maintain indices (which reduces RAM usage by eliminating key redundancy). I suggest trying it ;) and don't overlook the 16MB size limit.

Comment: I didn't get you point while stating " change the vendor in each shelf if he moves ".

Comment: Also isn't there too much document for each vendor if i insert shelves documents the way you have stated

Comment: One vendor has multiple shelves. So you still only have one vendor document. For my life, I wouldn't know a better way of modelling your data.

Comment: {
  "_id" : "vendor9",
  "cassette" : [{
      "shelf_no" : 1,
      "fruits" : ["Mango", "Banana"]
    }, {
      "shelf_no" : 2,
      "fruits" : ["Jackfruit"]
    }, {
      "shelf_no" : 3,
      "fruits" : ["Lemon", "Pulm", "Pineapple"]
    }, {
      "shelf_no" : 4,
      "fruits" : ["Orange", "Guava"]
    }]
}                                                                                                                             i am not able to resolve a) how to find shelf_no when any fruit and _id is known using find query .

Comment: However, using aggregation i am able to achieve result-   db.vendor.aggregate([ { "$match": { "_id": "vendor9" }},{ "$unwind": "$cassette" },{ "$unwind": "$cassette.fruits" },{ "$match": { "cassette.fruits": "Pulm" }},{ "$group": { "_id": "$_id","number": { "$addToSet": "$cassette.shelf_no"}}},{"$project": {"_id": 0, "number": 1 } }])

Comment: Which is neither faster nor more scalable than my solution, is it?